# What if maximumPoolSize is smaller than corePoolSize ? Possible bug in Java 6?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-6, threadpoolexecutor

I have encountered a weird problem with ThreadPoolExecutor of Java 6. From time to time when i have changed corePoolSize dynamically, i observed thread pool did not process as much task as it should have done.

For example, if i had 4 as corePoolSize and had lots of tasks waiting in the queue, the executor were processing 3 at most, sometimes 2 even.

When was investigating the problem, i noticed i have never changed maxPoolSize when i increased or decreased corePoolSize. It has always been 1 from the beginning of my application.

Never found a statement in Java's documentation mentioning the effect of maxPoolSize beeing smaller than core.

Then when i checked the source code, i have noticed both in costructor and setCorePoolSize methods, it gets checked where maximumPoolSize is smaller than corePoolSize, if so illegalArgumentException is thrown. Check out the codes below.

Constructor

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(
    int corePoolSize,
    int maximumPoolSize,
    long keepAliveTime,
    TimeUnit unit,
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
    ThreadFactory threadFactory,
    RejectedExecutionHandler handler
) {
    if (corePoolSize < 0 ||
        maximumPoolSize <= 0 ||
        maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize ||
        keepAliveTime < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (workQueue == null || threadFactory == null || handler == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    this.corePoolSize = corePoolSize;
    this.maximumPoolSize = maximumPoolSize;
    this.workQueue = workQueue;
    this.keepAliveTime = unit.toNanos(keepAliveTime);
    this.threadFactory = threadFactory;
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

setting max pool size

```
public void setMaximumPoolSize(int maximumPoolSize) {
    if (maximumPoolSize <= 0 || maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    try {
        int extra = this.maximumPoolSize - maximumPoolSize;
        this.maximumPoolSize = maximumPoolSize;
        if (extra > 0 && poolSize > maximumPoolSize) {
            try {
                Iterator<Worker> it = workers.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext() &&
                       extra > 0 &&
                       poolSize > maximumPoolSize) {
                    it.next().interruptIfIdle();
                    --extra;
                }
            } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
                // Not an error; it is OK if the threads stay live
            }
        }
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

So, clearly that is an unwanted situation. But there is no check in setCorePoolSize, that causes maximumPoolSize ending up smaller than corePoolSize, and the effect of this situation is not documented.

setting core pool size

```
public void setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize) {
    if (corePoolSize < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    try {
        int extra = this.corePoolSize - corePoolSize;
        this.corePoolSize = corePoolSize;
        if (extra < 0) {
            int n = workQueue.size(); // don't add more threads than tasks
            while (extra++ < 0 && n-- > 0 && poolSize < corePoolSize) {
                Thread t = addThread(null);
                if (t == null)
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (extra > 0 && poolSize > corePoolSize) {
            try {
                Iterator<Worker> it = workers.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext() &&
                       extra-- > 0 &&
                       poolSize > corePoolSize &&
                       workQueue.remainingCapacity() == 0)
                    it.next().interruptIfIdle();
            } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
                // Not an error; it is OK if the threads stay live
            }
        }
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Don't you think there should have been a mechanism preventing ending up with this case ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [newFixedThreadPool.setCorePoolSize() doesn't make use of the threads, creates new theads which may be overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044045/newfixedthreadpool-setcorepoolsize-doesnt-make-use-of-the-threads-creates-ne) => it is a reported bug.

Comment: @assylias Yes, seems like you have the answer there, and it is already submitted as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're right, there should be a test like

```
if (corePoolSize < 0 || corePoolSize > maxPoolSize)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

but you can easily test this before you call `setCorePoolSize` and adjust the maximum pool size if necessary. Even if such a test were there, you would have to check the maximum pool size before calling `setCorePoolSize` to avoid getting an `IllegalArgumentException`...